# Why is this unicode emoji showing as characters and not as an image when pushed live?

Tags: html, unicode, emoji

I have had an emoji in my website for months, but suddenly it's showing as the code or characters rather than as an image? When I look at it locally, it displays as it should, but when I view it on the live website, I get the characters instead. I have tried clearing my cache.

Also if I paste in a finger pointing upward it works. I'm sure this comes from a lack of understanding about how unicode works, but I haven't found a decent resource to help me.

Example for this :

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any code we can look into?

Answer (score 4):

The HTML is most likely not encoded in the charset that it (or the webserver) claims it is encoded in, causing the browser to interpret the data incorrectly.

The Emoji you have shown, U+1F447 (), is encoded as bytes `F0 9F 91 87` in UTF-8.  Those same bytes are `ðŸ‘‡` when interpreted as Latin-1.

You probably have your web browser configured to force the data to be interpreted as UTF-8, which would explain why you see the Emoji correctly.  Double-check your HTML's `<meta>` tags, and/or your webserver's `Content-Type` header, to make sure the correct charset is being reporting to browsers.

Alternatively, you can use HTML entities instead of raw UTF-8 octets, then you don't have to worry about charsets.  The HTML entity for U+1F447 can be written as either:

`&#128071;` (👇)

`&#x1f447;` (👇)